# Create base class for controller to extend/inherit in Ember application

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to create a Base Class for my controllers, so I can avoid duplication of code.

The problem here is that it is throwing me errors whenever I try to use it.

> "Assertion Failed: You attempted to define a `{{link-to "inventory"}}` but did not pass the parameters required for generating its dynamic segments. Could not find module `controllers/base-inventory` imported from `frontend/controllers/inventory`"

To create my base controller I am using ember cli and this is what I did:

```
ember g controller base-inventory
```

Then

```
// base-inventory.js
const BaseInventory = Ember.Controller.extend({
   //my code...
});
export default BaseInventory;
```

In the controller where I want to use this base class I did the following

```
import BaseInventory from 'controllers/base-inventory';
// also tried import { BaseInventory } from 'controllers/base-inventory';
// and  export default new BaseInventory({});
export default BaseInventory.extend({
    //more code here...
});
```

Any thoughts of what I am doing wrong?

I didn't plan to use mixins, because it doesn't seem the best option here at first. I am not really sure about the sharing content, which mixins provide. I don't think it would be a problem since I'm trying to inherit within controllers, but as I said I'm not sure about how it really works.

If it's not possible to do the way I'm trying to, I'll write a mixin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both files are in the same folder structure so import path should be like `./base-inventory`

```
import BaseInventory from './base-inventory';
```